# How to resolve this git error: git upload-pack: unable to fork git-pack-objects

Tags: git

```
$ git pull
fatal: git upload-pack: unable to fork git-pack-objects
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

I'm experiencing the above error, it is weird because this error is occuring on a machine where the repository is local. I can still push/pull from my computer to that remote machine. How can I resolve this short of deleting everything cloning it again?

Thanks.

Comment: What OS and which version of Git are you using? Recent versions (especially 1.7.0 and later) seem to have some additional error reporting that might be useful. Or, you might try running `GIT_TRACE=2 git pull` to see if it shows anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by making sure all git executables were available by the user in control of the repository.  Since yours is local, I can't see this being the issue, but I had the same problem with a remote repo and fixed it by making sure the git binaries were in my $PATH variable (unix)