# Git hook permission denied

Tags: git, githooks, ubuntu-20.04

When I am trying to run `git commit -m 'message here'` I am getting following error.

`fatal: cannot exec '.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg': Permission denied`

This issue started after when I created a new partition on my ubuntu and cloned the repo in it.

Comment: What git version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git cannot exec 'pack-objects': Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998540/git-cannot-exec-pack-objects-permission-denied)

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to make your file executable, the below code snippet will make the file executable for the owner, the group and the world:

```
$ chmod +x .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
```

Comment: Is the OP probably talking about an older version of git? With git 2.29.2 I'm getting `hint: The '.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg' hook was ignored because it's not set as executable.` and `git commit` still succeeds. Or is it a shell-related issue, not git?

Comment: @fluffy I can see that a check for non executable files was introduced in 2.13 see the commit https://github.com/git/git/commit/940283101ce87250cf31a592730386f5061e1286 I'm not sure which version OP is running.

Comment: The message was added later, in 2.14.3 https://github.com/git/git/commit/f805a00a396ee91599902cebe55620b2a4c813b9

Comment: I can see this phenomenon too, and I'm wondering where this hook is originating from, what creates it and why it is missing the step of making it executable. Any idea?

Comment: @HendrikWiese You created the file, either by creating it manually, by having used the `init.templatedir`, (`--templatedir`) when cloning / initializing a repository. Or if you have run a program that creates these hooks.

Comment: I think it's the latter. I'm just wondering which program that might be... I'm using GitKraken as git UI, IntelliJ IDEA/PyCharm as IDE... one of them _might_ be the culprit...

Comment: Or `chmod +x .husky/pre-commit` if you are using `husky`.

Answer (score 1):

For me I was getting the error `fatal: cannot exec '.git/hooks/pre-push': Permission denied`.

Applying Andreas's answer to this error message, I tried `$ chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-push`, and that fixed it. The subsequent `commit` and `push` commands went through successfully.

Apparently such `fatal: cannot exec ... : Permission denied` errors involving both git hooks can be resolved in the same way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34705247)

Answer (score 0):

For me, `chmod +x` for those git hooks did not help and I had to remove the file (move it to `{filename}.bak`).

I suppose this isn't a great solution, though.